# Checkboxes Require Double-Click to Change Active State

Tags: javascript, html

The checkboxes in my web app require two clicks to change their active state. Clicking once does not trigger the change immediately, and the checkboxes remain unresponsive until clicked again. These checkboxes have corresponding labels and are part of a larger form. When a user clicks on either checkbox, I expect it to become active immediately and stay active until the user selects the other checkbox. They shouldn't both be active at the same time. The buttons also trigger a `<select>` to appear.

I initially tried using event listeners for each checkbox to handle the change event. The event listener would remove the "checked" class from the other checkbox and add it to the current checkbox when clicked. Additionally, the script would dynamically show/hide two select dropdowns based on the selected checkbox. This is the initial code:

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-input');
const selectContainer = document.querySelector('.select-container');
const employeeLabel = document.querySelector('.employee-label');
const contractorLabel = document.querySelector('.contractor-label');
const employeeSelect = document.getElementById('employee-select');
const contractorSelect = document.getElementById('contractor-select');

checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
  checkbox.addEventListener('change', function() {
    checkboxes.forEach(otherCheckbox => {
      if (otherCheckbox !== this) {
        otherCheckbox.parentElement.classList.remove('checked');
      }
    });

    this.parentElement.classList.add('checked');

    if (checkbox.classList.contains('sms')) {
      selectContainer.style.display = 'block';
      employeeLabel.style.display = 'block';
      contractorLabel.style.display = 'none';
      employeeSelect.style.display = 'block';
      contractorSelect.style.display = 'none';
    } else if (checkbox.classList.contains('email')) {
      selectContainer.style.display = 'block';
      employeeLabel.style.display = 'none';
      contractorLabel.style.display = 'block';
      employeeSelect.style.display = 'none';
      contractorSelect.style.display = 'block';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-div sms-email">
  <label class="checkbox-container sms left" for="SmsCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input sms" id="SmsCheckbox" name="contactMethod">
      SMS
  </label>
  <label class="checkbox-container email right" for="EmailCheckbox">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input email right" id="EmailCheckbox" name="contactMethod">
      Email
  </label>
</div>
<label>Employee</label>
<select id="employee-select" name="type" class="custom_select">
  <!-- Options for Employee select -->
</select>
<label>Contractor</label>
<select id="contractor-select" name="type" class="custom_select">
  <!-- Options for Contractor select -->
</select>
```

I then tried to work around this by manually triggering the change event after setting the default value. Here's the JS that I changed:

```
 // Manually trigger the change event on the Employee checkbox to select it by default
 document.getElementById("SmsCheckbox").checked = true;
 document.getElementById("SmsCheckbox").parentElement.classList.add("checked");

 // Trigger the change event manually to apply the default selection
 document.getElementById("SmsCheckbox").dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

I really hope my formatting was okay with the question, if it's not I would really appreciate some pointers on better formatting for Stack questions as this is my first question! i appreciate any response or help, thank you!

Comment: JSFiddle if it helps for context! - https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=AtnxCPkp8r

Comment: Click [edit], then the `[<>]` snippet editor to add the [mcve] here

Comment: Your jsfiddle link doesn't work. I converted the code in the post to a stack snippet, but it gets an error because there's no `select-container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please delegate

Also you need to UNCHECK the other checkbox OR use a radio

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox-input');
  const selectContainer = document.querySelector('.select-container');
  const employeeLabel = document.querySelector('.employee-label');
  const contractorLabel = document.querySelector('.contractor-label');
  const employeeSelect = document.getElementById('employee-select');
  const contractorSelect = document.getElementById('contractor-select');
  const checkboxDiv = document.querySelector('.checkbox-div');
  checkboxDiv.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (!tgt.matches('.checkbox-input')) return;
    const sms = tgt.matches('.sms');
    // Only update the selection if the checkbox is checked
    checkboxes.forEach(checkbox => {
      checkbox.checked = checkbox === tgt;
      checkbox.closest('label').classList.toggle('checked', checkbox.checked); 
    });

    selectContainer.style.display = 'block';
    employeeLabel.hidden = !sms;
    contractorLabel.hidden = sms;
    // etc
  });

  // Manually trigger the change event on the Employee checkbox to select it by default
  const smsCheckbox = document.getElementById('SmsCheckbox');
  smsCheckbox.checked = true;
  smsCheckbox.parentElement.classList.add('checked');
  smsCheckbox.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
});
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-div sms-email">
  <label class="checkbox-container employee left" for="SmsCheckbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input sms" id="SmsCheckbox" name="contactMethod">
                    Employee
                  </label>
  <!--
                    --><label class="checkbox-container contractor right" for="EmailCheckbox">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox-input email right" id="EmailCheckbox" name="contactMethod">
                    Contractor
                  </label>
</div>
<div class="select-container">
  <label class="employee-label">Employee</label>
  <select id="employee-select" name="type" class="custom_select-jobs-for-supervisors-manage-allocate">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Choose Employee -</option>
    <option value="">Braeden Nairn</option>
    <option value="">Joshua Thomas-Butler</option>
    <option value="">Muhammed Ziauddin</option>
  </select>

  <label class="contractor-label" style="display: none;">Contractor</label>
  <select id="contractor-select" name="type" class="custom_select-jobs-for-supervisors-manage-allocate" style="display: none;">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>- Choose Contractor -</option>
    <option value="">SUBLIME-01</option>
    <option value="">SUBLIME-02</option>
    <option value="">SUBLIME-03</option>
  </select>
</div>
```